# vba controls.add

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to add a combobox to an existing form in excel vba. i have created a form named UserForm1 manually, then add a combobox to the form. Code as below:

```
Sub add_control()

Dim cmbFlow
Set cmbFlow = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.combobox.1", "cmbFlow", True)
With cmbFlow
    .Name = "cmbFlow"
    .Text = "check"
End With
UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.cmbFlow.Text = "new"
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

When i ran this code snippet, it gives an error

> "Compiler error: Method or data member not found".

And the breakpoint show "cmbFlow" is where the error comes.

i really cannot figure out what is wrong with this way. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Use UserForm1.Controls("cmbFlow").Text = "new" The control is not yet there in designmode and search for Userform1.show (it's better to show an instance of the form)

Comment: Declare `cmbFlow As MSForms.ComboBox` and then use the object itself: `cmbFlow.Text = "new"`. Then, in order to call it after the above code run, use the above suggestion way.  `UserForm1.Controls("cmbFlow").Text = "Newer"`...

Comment: But, even you can access and place a text in combo, this is not a big deal. Don't you need using the newly created combo events? Otherwise, it is only a way of playing with VBA...